# How to retrieve all document content from alfresco repository with seperation of document types using Open CMIS

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, opencmis

I Want to retrieve All document content from alfresco repository. So can anyone help me that how can i traverse the repository using CMIS. And while traversing i also want to separate the documents based on its type.

At this moment i am able to get any one document by specifying the path. but now my requirement is to traverse whole repository and get all the documents.

So can any one help me with this.
Also suggest me that "***Traversal of all folders and later separate by specific type***" will be the good approach OR "***Search specific type of document using CMIS query***" will be the good approach.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yagami's answer is a good start, but there are a few things to add.

First, do not do "select *" unless you actually need every single property the repository has. That is a potential performance problem. Only ask for what you need.

Second, one of your comments talks about segmenting results by type. In CMIS, a type is kind of like a SQL table. So in your case, you would do three different queries using each of your three custom types as a different type in the from clause:

```
select * from test:mainContract;
select * from test:subContract;
select * from test:royaltyStatement;
```

Finally, unless you have just a handful of documents in your repository, you are almost certainly going to want to use a paged result set. Otherwise, you will only get back the maximum number of results the server is configured to return. That may not be large enough to get the entire set.

For an example showing paging the result set, see [Apache CMIS: Paging query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100503/apache-cmis-paging-query-result)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It makes sense.

Comment: if i am querying select * from test:mainContract; Its giving only 1000 documents. But there are more that 1000 documents present in repository. So how can i get all the documents.... Can you please reply???

Comment: @Juff Potts   Can you please help me to fetch Aspect properties from alfresco repository. I have created one question for same. please help me if possible...

Answer (score 2):

To perform an action like this (getting all the document content) you need to follow this steps

***Step 1 : Create a saver Class***

What i mean with sever class, it will hold two information (for me it's the most valuable informations) the two of them most be character varying

1 - The document ID

2 - The document Name

***Step 2 : Get all the document***

To get all the document we have to use a query

```
String query;
query = "SELECT * FROM cmis:document ";
```

You will get all the document that you have in your repository.

You can add some condition to make your research more easier like in this example :

```
query = "SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE IN_FOLDER('" + folderId + "')";
```

In this example you will get document of a particular folder.

```
ItemIterable<QueryResult> resultList = session.query(query, false);
```

and finally

```
for (QueryResult qr : resultList) {    
String idDocument = qr.getPropertyByQueryName("cmis:objectId").getFirstValue().toString();
String name = qr.getPropertyByQueryName("cmis:name").getFirstValue().toString();
Document doc = (Document) session.getObject(idDocument);// this is how you can get document with add that's mean no need of path     
}
```

You can read more about query in [CMIS query](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-5898-cmis-query-language).

***Step 3 : Save every time the information in the saver class***

I think it's clear that you have to save every time you use the loop (in step 2) in an occurence of saver class.

I hope that helped you.

Comment: How can i separate the content according to content type? means i have total 4 different types of content in repository. and i want it separately. So can you please modify the answer if possible.

Comment: please give me this content type

Comment: test:mainContract, test:subContract and test:royaltyStatement these are the content types.......... and i want to separate all contents as per there content types

Comment: see in the link that i provide and see if you can find something like that, i was thinking that was document type

Comment: these are custom content types, but how can i separate the content according to these types. the query you provided will give all the contents. But inside that how can i apply filter..

Comment: it is a query you can add condition following what you need i will update my answer to make it clear

Comment: Instead of cm:document can't we search specific custom type of documents as per the document type or as per aspect?

Comment: need to do some research to answer about this question i've only tested getting document and folder sorry

Comment: Ok, Thanks @Yagami

Comment: if i am querying select * from cmis:document; Its giving only 1000 documents. But there are more that 1000 documents present in repository. So how can i get all the documents.... Can you please reply???