# CMIS how to fetch a document by it's objectId

Tags: alfresco, cmis

i'm trying to fetch document from alfresco using CMIS queries and all i have is there object id i tried the following but it returned 'bad request'

```
SELECT * FROM cmis:document where cmis:objectId = workspace://SpacesStore/89332e83-1a43-41fe-ba8d-2facdf317d05
```

I apologize i forgot to mention that i'm using CMIS with javascript
Thank you .

Comment: Why are you doing a query? Why not do a direct object fetch? (You haven't said what library you're using so we can't really help...)

Comment: how to do that with js ?

Comment: @Ayoub Idelhoussain was your question answered?

Comment: sadly not because im using JAVASCRIPT AND CMIS queries to fetch the data not java

Comment: Be careful about assuming that the Alfresco node reference, which is what you are showing, is the same thing as a CMIS object ID. They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

When you have the ID you don't need to use a query you can get it directly from the session object.

Typically for Java you can do something like this :

```
CmisObject cmisObject = session.getObject(id);

if (cmisObject instanceof Document) {
    Document document = (Document) cmisObject;
} else if (cmisObject instanceof Folder) {
    Folder folder = (Folder) cmisDocument;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplly with CMIS there is two ways to get an object (File or Folder) :

Before getting the object you need to get your alfresco session, read this post : [How to get Session in Alfresco using CMIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41626512/how-can-i-acces-to-an-alfresco-files-repository-using-cmis-rest-api/41640858#41640858).

***Getting an object by path***

```
CmisObject object = session.getObjectByPath(pathObject);
```

***Getting an object by ID***

```
CmisObject object = session.getObject(idObject);
```

After getting the object you can cast it to **File** or **Folder**

You can also read this post to understand how to get document with query using a Folder ID [How to get a document using Folder ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43449401/how-to-retrieve-all-document-content-from-alfresco-repository-with-seperation-of/43449913#43449913).

Hope that Helped you.