# Maven dependencies required in pom.xml for downloading a document from alfresco

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, alfresco, sts

In my java maven project there is a requirement to download documents from Alfresco.
I'm not able to figure out which are the dependencies to be added in the pom file for the same.
Hope some of you can help.

Thanks in advance...

Adding the maven dependencies I tried with

```
<!-- GROSS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.alfresco</groupId>
            <artifactId>alfresco-web-service-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.alfresco</groupId>
            <artifactId>alfresco-web-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.52</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ultimatixWPSWebServiceClient</groupId>
            <artifactId>ultimatixWPSWebServiceClient</artifactId>
            <version>19.1.1-1</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-el</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-el</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomahawk</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>xerces</groupId>
          <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

** AND I was getting error on server starting **

```
ERROR [org.apache.commons.digester.Digester] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 200) Parse Error at line 2 column 14: Document is invalid: no grammar found.: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jar:file:/D:/Softwares/jboss-eap-7.2/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as/jsf-injection/main/wildfly-jsf-injection-7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 14; Document is invalid: no grammar found.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What about the exec plugin calling wget or curl? What have you tried?

Comment: You can use cmis for that. FYI... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901006/cmis-how-to-fetch-a-document-by-its-objectid

Comment: I have added the dependencies that i tried with and the error i was getting on starting the server.

Comment: @sajay I wont be able to add that solution using CMIS, as i'm not aware of how to use it

Comment: What API are you trying to use to fetch the documents with? CMIS? Public API? Other?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 way you can download document from alfresco.

1. User alfresco rest-api  https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/
2. Use cmis in you java code. https://ecmarchitect.com/archives/tag/opencmis

Answer (score 0):

Please give a try with the latest version of the alfresco web service client, seems like you are using a old version.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.alfresco/alfresco-web-service-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.alfresco</groupId>
    <artifactId>alfresco-web-service-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.a</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.alfresco/alfresco-web-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.alfresco</groupId>
    <artifactId>alfresco-web-client</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.f</version>
</dependency>
```

Also you can use the Rest api explorer if you were using Alfresco 5.2 or higher to download a document.

https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#!/nodes/getNodeContent